Whenever I using ec2 instance and accessing Jenkins via putty after some seconds it's connection get lost.what will be the reasons?
When I started Jenkins it's connection get lost after some seconds
I started ec2 and connected to putty
And started the services and installed all packages required for Jenkins setup.alao installed java and it's dependencies.

The reason is some configured time out somewhere. Can be in lots of different parts of the stack.
